# how to change order of statically created layouts in a linear layout dynamically? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout created with XML code. which has a `scrollview` and in that scroll view there are two relative layouts

here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#151515">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <ImageView
                    android:onClick="monday"
                    android:id="@+id/monday"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_145sdp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mondaysmolgray" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_70sdp"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mondaydate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" No tasks"
                        android:textColor="#151515"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mondaytasks"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text=" No tasks"
                        android:textColor="#151515"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mondaytodos"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text=" No tasks"
                        android:textColor="#151515"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"></TextView>


                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <ImageView
                    android:onClick="tuesday"
                    android:id="@+id/tuesday"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_145sdp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tuesdaysmolgray" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_70sdp"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tuesdaydate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" No tasks"
                        android:textColor="#151515"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tuesdaytasks"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text=" No tasks"
                        android:textColor="#151515"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tuesdaytodos"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text=" No tasks"
                        android:textColor="#151515"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"></TextView>


                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

as you can see there two relative layouts inside a scroll view.
I want to change the order of two linear layouts dynamically from without creating the whole thing again in runtime code. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reorder methods in android layout.

So you can try to remove all views with `removeView(view)`.

And then you need to add them with `addView(childView, index)` in that order you like.

in your case need to define id to parent LinearLayout and two RelativeLayouts.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/first">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/second">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**In JAVA Code:**

```
ViewGroup container = findViewById(R.id.container);
View first = findViewById(R.id.first);
View second = findViewById(R.id.second);
container.removeView(first);
container.addView(first); // append first view to last.
```